# How to combine two bars of a bar chart in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have the below image created using tableau. I would like to combine values 19 and 20 and beyond (on the x axis) to form one combined bar chart while keeping the rest of the bars intact.  How can I do so? The end result in this case will a value of 6 for x-axis (>= 19). Preferably changing the x-axis naming convention to reflect the aggregation of the values.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the bars which you wish to combine and click on create groups.  You can thereafter rename groups too.

See

[image]

[image]

Comment: as soon as you create a group, the grouped field will appear in `dimension and measures` pane, which you can edit by right clicking it

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you in this case we have 2 bars to group. However not all the times it is 2. Can i create a condition whereby >= 19 is the same group

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Please accept and upvote as usually desired on SO.  Actually, you may have converted 19, 20,.. values to dimension earlier before creating chart.  So grouping dimension on condition is not unfortunately not possible.  There may be other workarounds for the same.  Please give some data, in that case